# IBM HTTP 8.5 failing to start with error (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

Tags: apache, https, webserver, ibmhttpserver

I have a IBM HTTP 8.5 webserver which is configured as load balancer for websphere application servers.
now to enable security on HTTP 8.5 i configured SSL with 443 PORT .
When i tried restarting i am getting below error

i tried with both mqm user and sudo user .
HTTP installed folder is having full permission for mqm

$  ./apachectl start
[Fri Jul 25 11:54:37 2014] [warn] module proxy_balancer_module is already loaded, skipping
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Comment: Only user with root privileges can open ports below 1024. Just for test try to change that port for example to 8443 to see if it will start correctly.

Comment: yes if i change the port it wil start with mqm user itself.

Comment: So your user doesn't have permissions. You need to start apache from root user or using $  sudo -u root /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl start